# wp_get_nav_menu_items Adding class to the child of a child from a parent

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` to obtain the menu items from my website. Having a parent menu items with 2 children menu items and adding a class to it if it's active works. However, nesting another child, inside the parents child won't add a class to the child element.

I am trying to add a class to the primary parent instead of child parent.

```
<?php $menu_lp_location = 'landingpage'; ?>

<?php if ( has_nav_menu( $menu_lp_location ) ) : ?>
<?php $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( wp_get_nav_menu_name( $menu_lp_location ) ); ?>

<ul class="gap-3 px-3 py-1.5 bg-white justify-center shadow-xl border border-black sm:shadow-none sm:border-none md:shadow-none rounded-md btn-group md:flex m-2 fixed bottom-0 left-0 md:m-0 right-0 sm:relative">
    <?php
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) :
    $menu_item_class = ( $menu_item->object_id == get_queried_object_id() || $post->post_parent == $menu_item->object_id ) ? 'bg-sun' : esc_attr( implode( '', $menu_item->classes ) );
    $menu_item_parent_child_class = ( $post->post_parent == $menu_item->object_id ) ? 'bg-sun' : '';

    echo $menu_item_parent_child_class;
    print_r ( $post );
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= esc_url( $menu_item->url ) ?>" target="<?= esc_attr( $menu_item->target ?: '_self' ) ?>" class="text-[11px] md:text-sm btn btn-sm btn-ghost <?= $menu_item_class ?>" title="<?= $menu_item->title ?>"><?= esc_html( $menu_item->title ) ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```